# How to find a difference between consecutive rows of a same group?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, group-by

This question was asked in Facebook interview:

(1) There are Two tables

- attendances : date | student_id | attendance
- students : student_id | school_id | grade_level | date_of_birth | hometown

Using this data, could you answer questions like the following:

- Which grade level had the largest drop in attendance between yesterday and today?

So far, I have got this and I am stuck. Can you help me? Thanks.

```
(SELECT grade_level, date, COUNT(attendance) AS att FROM attendances AS A
     LEFT JOIN students AS S
     ON A.student_id = S.student_id
     GROUP BY grade_level, date
     HAVING attendance == "yes"
     AND (date == "02-06-2020" OR date == "02-05-2020")
     ORDER BY grade_level, date DESC) AS t
```

Comment: Aside: SQLite3 does not have an explicit date type. For correct results one would define dates as `YYYY-MM-DD`.  Although equality may work in your example, other operations such as `between` or `order by` normally won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join the tables, do conditional aggregation, then sort and limit:

```
select
    s.grade_level
    sum(a.attendance * case when a.date = date('now') then 1 else -1 end) attendance_drop
from attendances a
inner join students s on s.student_id = a.student_id
where a.date in (date('now'), date('now', '-1 day'))
group by s.grade_level
order by attendance_drop desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below script think it is working fine.

```
SELECT TOP 1 s.grade_level, COUNT(a.attendance) AS dropCount 
FROM students  AS s
INNER JOIN attendances AS a ON  a.student_id = s.student_id
WHERE 
    a.attendance = 'no'
    AND (a.date <= DATEADD(DAY,-1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND a.date >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
GROUP BY s.grade_level
ORDER BY dropCount DESC
```